# Are there any good resources where I can listen to very casual real English conversations among native speakers?

Tags: english, listening, conversation

When watching a video on Netflix or Youtube, I can usually easily understand English conversations.

However, when it comes to real conversations among native speakers, I sometimes cannot even understand what they are talking about at all. I assume it’s partly because of the lack of common knowledge, but I often cannot simply pick up their sounds and words because, to me, it sounds like they are mumbling.

So, I’m looking for videos, social media, and other types of resources where I can immerse myself in very casual and real English conversations among native speakers.

I would appreciate it if you could tell me good ones.

---

[Added based on the comment]

As you assumed, I have already tried watching movies and videos on a daily basis on Netflix and Amazon Prime, and I can usually follow the conversations without subtitles. (I check subtitles only when they use words I don't know.)

I suppose I can say, in terms of understanding conversations in movies, I have no problem because they are pronounced clearer than conversations in real life.

So, I guess my largest problem is understanding very casual pronunciation in real conversations, not in movies, and I wanted to ask where I can listen to real-life native conversations online.

Comment: Why don't you consider something straightforward like watching movies online? For a cheap monthly subscription you would have subtitles to read what they say; also many content providers have multiple audio tracks including your native language if you're really stuck with the translation. Note that watching movies/documentaries about the topic you're already interested about and familiar with is a huge benefit by itself. *(this is a comment, not an answer because I assume you've tried it and you may wish to narrow down your question by telling why it didn't work in your case)*

Comment: Come on now, a lot of the stuff on Netflix etc. are like conversations among/between real speakers. Where are you now hearing these conversations between "real speakers" you cannot understand??

Comment: Searching _**English news or interviews with subtitles**_ on youtube will get you much further than waiting for an answer here...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I first came to the UK. The diversity of accents was quite confusing to my ear used to American English. But the good news is that you will get used to it.

What you call real English conversations is pretty vague though. There are so many varieties and you must focus your search to a certain extent. If you are interested for example in British accents, you can listen to BBC radio stations which are available for most UK regions:

- [BBC Wales](https://www.bbc.co.uk/sounds/play/live:bbc_radio_wales_fm)
- [BBC Essex](https://www.bbc.co.uk/sounds/play/live:bbc_radio_essex)
- [BBC Cornwall](https://www.bbc.co.uk/sounds/play/live:bbc_radio_cornwall) etc.

As for videos look for interviews or simply regional news. Don't give up easily. Especially in learning languages I have found that if there is a will there's a way.